# Select columns by choosing maximum value in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine the following exemplary table:

```
time      name     value1 value2
12:00     Hans     2      4
12:30     Hans     2      4
13:00     Hans     3      5
14:00     Peter    4      4
15:00     Peter    4      4
```

I want to filter by maximum time stamp and name.

Meaning I want to get

```
13:00     Hans     3      5
15:00     Peter    4      4
```

Using `select max(time),name,value1,value2 from table group by name`
does not work. It tells me to use an aggregate function or group by on value1 and value2 also.

If I group by name, value1 and value2 then I get the following result though since value1 and value2 are different for two rows of Hans:

```
12:30     Hans     2      4
13:00     Hans     3      5
15:00     Peter    4      4
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: [Name of the RDBMS is `PostgreSQL`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F), or a shorter `Postgres`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `max(time)` for each `name` and then join that back to your table to get the final result:

```
select t1.time,
  t1.name,
  t1.value1,
  t1.value2
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(time) MaxTime, name
  from yourtable
  group by name
) t2
  on t1.time = t2.maxtime
  and t1.name = t2.name
```

Depending on the database that you are using, if you can apply a windowing function like `row_number()` or `rank()`, then your query would be similar to the following:

```
select time, name, value1, value2
from
(
  select time, name, value1, value2,
    rank() over(partition by name order by time desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c06e8/2) of both queries

Comment: Works totally great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `distinct on` it is quite simple. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/25a69/2)

```
select distinct on (name)
    "time", name, value1, value2
from t
order by t.name, t."time" desc
```